# How to configure the Deployer for SmartTarget

Tags: content-delivery, smarttarget

Which is a good option for configuring the Deployer with Smart Target, i.e. a separate Deployer or use the existing `Deployer/HttpUpload` for the website?

Comment: Can you provide a better scenario of your environment and what you feel is best / why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the most common scenario you would use the existing Deployer. Having an extra target means users have to double publish / unpublish from two additional targets, plus there is the overhead of maintaining extra targets (consider upgrades etc).

Also consider content is dynamic and can come from the Broker. So if a user only publishes to ST (and not the broker) there could be an issue where the identifier from ST is returned which then returns nothing from the broker.

I'd rather the publishing fails in both site and SmartTarget in the event of failure.

Business requirements will likely dictate the publishing architecture, and there may be specific scenarios where one may want to have separate targets. Tridion is flexible enough to support both approaches.

Comment: I'm confused; what answer are you disagreeing with? Nick's answer also said to use the existing Deployer.

Comment: @PeterKjaer yes i wasn't clear, i've updated my answer

Comment: Can you clarify your second paragraph please? What do you mean results from ST can come from the Broker?

Comment: I think that he means that ST queries only return the ComponentID and TemplateID of each promotion result, then the corresponding CP is actually displayed from the Tridion Broker, usually using tridion:ComponentPresentation control or taglib. So if you use 2 targets, you can have inconsistencies between content indexed in FH versus content in the Tridion Broker. A ST/FH query may return a result which is not available in the Broker, so nothing is displayed on your page. Thus I would not recommend to use a separate target for ST.

Answer (score 5):

Typically you would use the existing one, since you still want your Component Presentations to be published normally so that your content gets into the broker as well as into SmartTarget.

Comment: What if your content isn't going into the broker?

Comment: Doesn't matter, John - the point is that you want it to be deployed as normal and then also to Fredhopper. So if you were to set up a separate deployer, you'd need to duplicate all of the existing setup and then add SmartTarget on top of that. You can do that, of course, but there's no compelling reason to when you can just add to the existing setup.